# Prescribing color to index matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am making a gif which looks like this.

[image]

As you can see, the order changes with time. I would like the colour to stay the same, when the order changes. How can I prescribe colour to index?

My data looks like this:

```
Country Name             1960  etc
Mauritius                0.12
Trinidad and Tobago      0.15
Namibia                  0.16
Oman                     0.22
United Arab Emirates     0.20
```

And related part of code like this, as you can see I am making sorting before prescribing colours, hence the colour changes, how can I make it work?

```
for i in years:
    newdf=newdf.sort_values(by=[str(i)])
    ax = newdf.plot.barh(y=str(i), rot=0 ,color=['cyan', 'blue', 'green', 'red', 'black'])
```

Comment: you have to add a column with the colors and then put it into the plot `color=newdf['color]`

Comment: Thanks, didnt think of it.